# Mixing countability; how to correctly say "there is plenty of rice, earthquakes and typhoons"?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, sentence-patterns, countable-nouns

In [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/83874/61071) I wrote the following sentence, knowing full well that it has problems.

> Where I live right now there is plenty of rice, earthquakes and typhoons.

Both earthquake and typhoon are countable nouns, while rice in this context is probably considered uncountable.

I could split this up into two sentences, or separate the rice from the other two within the sentence, for example: *Where I live right now there are plenty of earthquakes and typhoons to go along with the rice* although I'm sure someone else could find a more graceful way to do it.

There are some possibly helpful recommendations in [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/149172/217285) but I'm not sure how to apply them here.

But here I am asking if there is a way that I can keep the three nouns as close together as possible.

Comment: Related: [Mixing plural and singular list items with a single verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59808/mixing-plural-and-singular-list-items-with-a-single-verb), [uncountable noun + and + uncountable noun](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/166825/uncountable-noun-and-uncountable-noun), [“There Is”/“There are” depends on plurality of the first list element or not?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140854)

Comment: Since there's a dichotomy between the positive (lots of rice) and negative (natural disasters) aspects, perhaps: "_Where I live right now there is plenty of rice, **but also** many earthquakes and typhoons._"

Comment: @TripeHound that's a good idea, and while written like that it makes my sentence look worse, that's because of the sentence itself. I might keep *plenty* in the second half as well for consistency; *there is plenty of X, but plenty of Y and Z as well*.

Comment: Where I live we certainly have enough rice, and typhoons, and earthquakes... In some cases more than enough.

Comment: Juxtaposing rice with natural disasters is incongruous, so this only works in a quirky register. Is that intended, or can you provide a different example where unnaturalness due to quirkiness isn't a complicating factor? / A simple rewrite ( 'Where I live right now, we have plenty of rice, earthquakes and typhoons.') retains the wryness and colloquial flavour.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth juxtaposition and incongruity are literary tools and not necessarily quirky. In fact, the quirky label is subjective, and I'm not sure how I could know ahead of time which incongruous juxtapositions you are going to deem to be quirky and which not. Maybe you could suggest some?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OP asks: “But here I am asking if there is a way that I can keep the three nouns as close together as possible”

One sentence.

> Earthquakes and typhoons are **as plentiful as** rice where I live.

Comment: I've got to just accept this because it is exactly what I am looking for! You've solved my grammatical problem and also found a much better way to express what I wanted to at the same time, and so I've made the change in the [original location](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/83874/61071). Thank you!

Comment: @uhoh that was unexpected. Thank you for vote of confidence. I see you posted over 7 hours ago, so you must have been feeling slightly frustrated. Well, you never know someone else might post a better answer. If they do, feel free to accept theirs.

Comment: @uhoh you could swap the order, "Rice is as plentiful as the earthquakes and typhoons where I live". I've only just read your post on SE Seasoned Advice.

Comment: We often have a typhoon and an earthquake three times in a single day? This has to be in a marked (quirky) register.